# Saving the data in database table using dialog box in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, dialog

I am creating one dialog box in MVC 4 using C# In this dialog box I have three checkboxes which I have put in div!

Now on the click of save button in that dialog box

I want the values of the checked check-boxes to get stored the table. I have written a stored procedure for that. 
In my controller I have a action called as Edit where this entire database code is written.

I tried ajax call but I am getting 'Not Found' msg from webpage!

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please post your code from the view and the controller action.

Comment: `Not found` usually means the request URL, or request type, does not match the Ajax request. 1) Use a tool like Fiddler2 to see what is being sent and 2) try the URL directly using the Fiddler composer.

Comment: I suspect there is a problem with your Form Tag and or your route configuration.  Post your Html for the form being submitted and your route configuration in global.asax

Comment: Thanks people. The problem is solved now. The error was there in the variables I was declaring to be used inside ajax call.